# change fastcgi directory in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, unix, fastcgi

i am not sure how to write the proper title 
i have 5 ajax requests that gonna execute postgresql query in php

here is the directory

```
/var/www/webgis.com:
1. webgis.html
2. php(directory)
    -query1.php
    -query2.php
    -query3.php
    -query4.php
    -query5.php
3.etc
```

the all previous ajax url is `url: "php/query(N).php"`, i want to change it into`url: "query(N).php"`  without change my server directory 
i use this script but doesn't work

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        set $php_root /var/www/webgis.com/php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

can somebody help me/ tell me what should i write?

Comment: Try: `location = /kuery1.php { rewrite ^ /php/quer1.php last; }`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i already edit the question, i mean.. i want to remove "/php" directory in all url ajax request.. but without moving php script into parents directory..